How to create a composite index ASC and DESC on EntityTypeConfiguration
I have a composite index in SQL Server:
CREATE INDEX IX_PetServiceId_Rate 
ON PetCenterService (PetServiceId ASC, Rate DESC)

But my project is database-first so I try to config that composite index before migrate but I don't know how to create it in EF:
builder.HasIndex(x => new { x.PetServiceId ASC, x.Rate DESC })
       .HasDatabaseName("IX_PetServiceId_Rate")
       .IsUnique(false);


which version of entity framework / .NET ?

what is the issue with the code you posted? according to the documentation, it seems correct for recent versions of EF core

ahh and now I understand your actual issue. In the documentation there is the annotation : [Index(nameof(Url), nameof(Rating), IsDescending = new[] { false, true })] . How did you solve it ?

What was the solution?

This my solution:
        builder.HasIndex(x => new { x.PetServiceId, x.Rate })
        .HasDatabaseName("IX_PetServiceId_Rate")
        .IsDescending([false, true])
        .IsUnique(false);

